# How to find autocorrelation and plot_acf on python using data with unequal time intervals?

Tags: python, pandas, statsmodels, autocorrelation

I have a following pandas series where the time interval is not fixed. May I ask how do I find and plot the autocorrelation for 1/3/5/10 minutes? Sorry I am new to python... These are trade datas where price changes. As the price can change at anytime, hence the time data is not of fixed interval. But I would need to study the autocorrelation at 1,3,5 and 10 minutes and have thought of using plot_acf.

```
time                           Price
2019-01-07 07:45:01.064515    152.530
2019-01-07 07:45:01.110072    152.535
2019-01-07 07:45:01.116596    152.535
2019-01-07 07:45:01.116860    152.535
2019-01-07 07:45:01.116905    152.535
```

This is my code:

```
interval = datetime.timedelta(minutes = 10)
series = pd.Series(data_first_session['fair_price'].values, index = data_first_session['time'])
acf = plot_acf(series, lags = interval)
acf.show()
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-5307c2c9f4df> in <module>()
      1 interval = datetime.timedelta(minutes = 10)
      2 series = pd.Series(data_first_session['fair_price'].values, index = data_first_session['time'])
----> 3 acf = plot_acf(series, lags = interval)
      4 acf.show()

/usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/graphics/tsaplots.py in plot_acf(x, ax, lags, alpha, use_vlines, unbiased, fft, title, zero, **kwargs)
    109     fig, ax = utils.create_mpl_ax(ax)
    110 
--> 111     lags, nlags, irregular = _prepare_data_corr_plot(x, lags, zero)
    112 
    113     confint = None

/usr/local/envs/py3env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/statsmodels/graphics/tsaplots.py in _prepare_data_corr_plot(x, lags, zero)
     18     else:
     19         irregular = True
---> 20         lags = np.asanyarray(lags).astype(np.int)
     21     nlags = lags.max(0)
     22 

TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Comment: Typo in your `plot_acf` method..? Should be `lags` rather than `lag`

Comment: I will give it a try but may I ask if the logic or the code is correct? @ChrisA

Comment: Don't think so, `lags` param should be int or an array of `ints`. Passing `timedelta` will fail

Comment: yea I have tried it throws an error regarding lags param should be an integer... if that's the case do you have any idea how should I approach this?

Comment: try resampling your timeseries to 1 minute intervals, and pass in lags `[1, 3, 5, 10]` ...?  so maybe `series.resample('1min').mean()` ..?

Comment: Haha I got a y=0 graph